# Image of complex function $f$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ be a complex function. We have to look at values in the plane given by $$P = \{ z \ | \ -\text{Im}(z) < \text{Re}(z) < \text{Im}(z)\}$$I need to describe the image of $f$ under $P$. I don't know how to find it. I tried to write the function the following way $$\frac{z-i}{z+i} = \frac{x+(y-1)i}{x+(y+1)i} \cdot \frac{x-(y+1)i}{x-(y+1)i} = \frac{x^2+y^2-1}{x^2+(y+1)^2} - \frac{2x}{x^2+(y+1)^2}i$$ But I don't know how I can find the image of $f$ when I have found this. Can somebody help me?

Comment: the domain a sector between angles $45, 135$ in the upper half-plane so see what happens on the two half-lines (image is inside the unit circle and it touches it only at $\pm 1$ corresponding to $0, \infty$ on the boundary

Answer (score 1):

This is the Cayley transformation.  It's well known that Mobius transformations map the Riemann sphere $\hat{\Bbb C}$ bijectively onto itself.

It maps the upper half plane conformally onto the unit disk.  The lower half plane goes to the exterior of the disk.  $-i\mapsto\infty$.

This particular transformation gives an isomorphism between the Poincaré upper half plane model, and that of the unit disk.

See what happens to the boundary lines of $P$.  Mobius transformations map generalized circles to generalized circles.  We have $0\mapsto-1,1-i\mapsto1-2i,\infty\mapsto1$.  Those three points determine a circle.  Then as a test point, $i\mapsto0$.  So, it maps the half plane above $y=-x$ to the interior of the circle.

For the other boundary line, $y=x$, $f$ maps it to the circle determined by $-1,1/(1+2i)$ and $1$.  Then since $-i\mapsto\infty$, we get the interior of the circle.

So, $f(P)$ is the intersection of the interior of the first circle and the interior of the second.